# Replacement of a ceramic smd capacitor without diagram or screen printing

Tags: capacitor, schematics, surface-mount, capacitance

I was tasked with trying to repair a Samsung motherboard from a NP740u3M laptop with a BA92-16998A model board, a drink has been spilled there. It is a fault of ceramic smd capacitors. I'm looking for the diagram / schematic of this model that I couldn't find anywhere as I need to have a reference to the capacitance of capacitors, ICs, and other components. I would greatly appreciate any help anyone can give me.

[image: These are the capacitors, I read you can tell their capacitance by their size.]

Comment: Why do you think it's a cap that's dead? They're not the type of part that would be easily damaged by liquid.

Comment: @Drew They are shorted. I have tested them, they are the ones near the source buck.

Comment: It's probably not the capacitor that is shorted but rather something else on the same circuit.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to determine what the capacitor values are is difficult at best. The rest of the circuit can change the value of the capacitors, so they must be desoldered from the board and measured with a capacitance meter (many high end DMM's or smart tweezers have this function). You may be able to get some mileage out of smart tweezers and measuring in place.

The capacitors are likely not faulty (it is more likely that the residue is affecting the timing), get some PCB cleaner (like techspray) and thoroughly clean the PCB until all residue is removed and hope for the best.  Because if the motherboard was shorted while it was on, it's likely that there are many other components that were damaged.

Answer (score 0):

Try washing the area with isopropyl alcohol 90% or greater or soap and water followed by a good rinse and dry. That should solve it. Yes it was more than likely rinsed with water when it was manufactured. On my SMD and through hole prototypes I rinse with hot water, add a drop of dish soap, scribe with a soft nylon bristle brush. After that I simply rinse with hot water then thoroughly dried.